# Storing "total cash earned" data into Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web application where users can play a game. If the user wins, she will get money into her account; in the other hand, if the user loses the game, she will lose money as well. I need to store the data "total money earned" and "total money lost" into a Database.

The problem is that, if some malicious user gets access to the database, that user will be able to change all the "total money earned" and "total money lost", and that is a big problem.

At first glance I thought this problem could be totally avoided by encrypting the "total money earned" and "total money lost", but suddenly I realised that this wouldn't work, as this hypothetical malicious user could always change those value to whatever he wants.

This question is not about ""How to avoid users to access my Database"", but rather about "if a malicious user gets access to it, how can I prevent my data to be changed?""

Comment: If a user gets access to your DB, you're pretty much SOL, as they would probably do more damage than just cheat in your little game.

Comment: @RocketHazmat true in most situations but if you redundancy copies with different credentials you can recoup any data loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Starting point:

You could checkout what `Magento` does with its `sales_order` table information.

Each row in the `sales_order` table represents an individual order issued by a customer. There are protection mechanisms in the admin that do not allow admins to edit these orders. You can only cancel the previous and create a new cloned order (if the initial order really needs to be "changed").

At the table level there is a column called `protect_code`. This code is (i'm speculating) generated as a cryptographic hash ([hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.hash-hmac.php) with any one of the algorithms: md5, sha1, sha2, sha256, etc.) of the entire order information object.

If the order information object is hashed using a secure key that the perpetrator does not have access to (for example the hacker has accessed your database but not your PHP code) then he will not be able to alter the values of the order information object because he will also need to update the hash and without using the same secure key he will not be able to obtain the same hash.

You will be able to recognize any row that has been tampered with by recalculating the hash.

### Background info:

Normally keys like this are stored in PHP and the hashes are presented to the user within payment forms, to make sure the user cannot change the payment information before sending the form to the payment gateway (a separate website).

Both your PHP application and the payment gateway application share the cryptographic key, because the payment gateway has to hash the data it receives and check that it hasn't been tampered with (by comparing hashes). Usually you receive your (own dedicated) cryptographic key from the payment gateway.

This implies that the user/hacker does not know your cryptographic key and cannot access your PHP server (meaning he can't read the key either).

### Anything you use is accessible:

If the user has access to your application server that means he can have access to any and all 3rd party services (secured or not), such as databases, file storage servers, payment services, mail sending services etc.. The only exemption from this rule is if your application server is just an aggregator for other self hosted self contained services.

If the user has access to the database server but not the application server, your cryptographic key should be safe and your data should be hard to tamper with undetected (but not hard to alter or delete).

If you are using a tiny bit of data anywhere in your application an the user/hacker has access to the application server that means that he (the hacker) has access to that data. You can even store the cryptographic keys on a separate server and obtain each of them by request, if the user/hacker has access he can request them too. If your app is using them, your hacker can be using them too.

Comment: Thank you for the info! One question: is the key of the hash stored inside the php file? In that case, a new question arises? isn't there any way for the malicious user to access it? Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: I've added a brackground info heading explaining how cryptographic keys are used and where they are normally saved.

Answer (score 6):

This is just basic server security. If somebody logs into your MySQL database as a user with write privleges there is nothing you can do. You have to stop them beforehand.

Steps you can take:

1) Have strong server passwords and user account design. Don't have people SSH in as root is a no-brainer example.

2) Give your application only as much access to the database as it needs. Don't have your application be allowed to drop tables for instance if it does not need to. This will at least mitigate possible damage.

3) Be sure you are protected against SQL injection. This is probably the number 1 mistake noobies make.

There is of course tons more to know, but there are more books than you can read in a lifetime on the subject of security. I advise you look into one. I highly recommend Essential PHP security for your PHP code. Its small concise and informative.

Comment: Hello thatidiotguy, thanks for your answer. Of course to write data into "total money earned" and "total money lost", it is a must to be able to write into that Table, so "writting in" is a privilege. But as I can write in, some other users can also do it.

Comment: @EstrellaGarcía Not unless they know your access credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to understand is that there is no silver bullet with regards to keeping your data secure. From securing access to your server by ensuring only the necessary ports for communication are open to using strong username and passwords to ensuring that the DB user has only the rights required to perform the tasks necessary. It really is a broad topic. I suggest you search the web for OWASP. If an unauthenticated user is able to gain access to your data your encryption is the least of your worries.

For your situation encrypting is fine but consider using a user specific salt and keeping your encryption method safe.